# Error Code #1009 For Copter Style Dodge Game AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Can you please look at my code and tell me why I am getting this Error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at Arm/update()

I am **NOT** using document classes as I just learned and could not get those to work.
Here is the tutorial I started from: http://eyes-squared.co.uk/blog/making-a-copter-style-game-the-projects/

MAIN CODE:

```
stop();


import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


var mouseIsDown = false; // mouse isn't held at start
var speed = 0; // no speed at the start
var score = 0; // start with no score!

// check for collisions every frame
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
// add 2 event listeners for the mouse button
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clicked);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, unclicked);

// explain the mouse functions
function clicked(m:MouseEvent) {
    mouseIsDown = true;
}

function unclicked(m:MouseEvent) {
    mouseIsDown = false;
}

//// explain the main game loop
function mainLoop(e:Event) {
    // update the score!
    score = score + 10;
    // update the text field
    Output.text = "Score: "+score;
    // move the player based on the mouse button
    if (mouseIsDown) {
        // take something off the speed
        speed -= 2; // accelerate upwards
    } else {
        speed += 2;
    }
    // limit the speed
    if (speed > 10) speed = 10;
    if (speed < -10) speed = -10;
    // move the player based on the speed
    firefly.y += speed;
    // loop through everything on screen
    for (var i = 0; i<numChildren; i++) {
        // check to see if this object is a block
        if (getChildAt(i) is Block || getChildAt(i) is Boundary || getChildAt(i) is Block2 || getChildAt(i) is Arm) {
            var b = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
            // this means the object is a block
            // check the block against the player object
            if (b.hitTestObject(firefly)) {
                // make an explosion
                for (var counter = 0; counter<12; counter++) {
                    // make a new Boom object
                    var boom = new Boom();
                    boom.x = firefly.x;
                    boom.y = firefly.y;
                    // randomly rotate boom
                    boom.rotation = Math.random()*360;
                    // randomly scale it
                    boom.scaleX = boom.scaleY = 0.5+Math.random();
                    // add the boom to the world
                    addChild(boom);
                }
                // hide the player
                firefly.visible = false;
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);

                if(b.hitTestObject(firefly)){
                    nextFrame();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugger. Please try to reduce your problem to a minimal case (you might even fix it yourself). Also your title should be made more relevant to the question.

Comment: Try to figure out why the reference is NULL.

Comment: Do you have any code on the timeline for any of your movieclips ?

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, your error refers to a function called `update()` inside a class / MovieClip called Arm, which isn't included in your initial post.

Assuming that you don't have any code in classes, and everything is inside the FLA, look in the Library panel in the Flash IDE for the object called Arm, open that, and then look inside the frame script(s) there for the `update()` function.

The specific error means that you're trying to perform an action on (or inspect a property of) an object that hasn't been created yet, or otherwise doesn't exist. For instance, if you've deleted or relabelled a named object inside that Arm symbol, which is then being referenced in the update function, it will run into the null object error.

If you look at the code and are still struggling to see which object is null, try placing the following trace statements in between each line in the update function:

```
trace(1);
...
trace(2);
...
```

Because this is a run time error, Flash will trace out the given number at every line until it hits that error, and it drops the thread. Watch the output panel to see which numbers are traced, and you will know that the faulty line is directly after the highest number traced. Then you can think about why something on that line might be null. Good luck!